# Jquery-ui autocomplete won't work in a specific only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Been trying for 2 days and appreciate any help.  I can get autocomplete to work outside of the div I am trying to make it work in.  The specific div, input field, does not work.

I have tried as others mentioned setting the 
    .ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 50000 !important;
    } to the class, but still doesn't work.

Here is a link to the test page.  The div is "destinations" front and center.
    http://www.inidaho.com/responsive/test4.asp

Here is my header code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/glyphicons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/iitheme.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,500italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran"
];
$("#destination").autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
```

and here is the input I am trying to autocomplete

```
<form id="home-searchform" class="home-searchform">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-med-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center ui-widget">
<label for="destination">destination</label>
<input id="destination" name="destination" placeholder="Choose Destination">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-med-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
<input type="button" name="submit" value="GO" class="ui-btn med ui-main txt-    center"/>
</div>
</form>
```

I have tried to format the code above correctly, but am having trouble so apologize.  Any suggestions are appreciated. Best.

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/opd728g0/2/

Comment: Thanks Arun, it does work outside of the container div of the actual page and in jsfiddle, but not on the actual website.  Feel like something in the container div is blocking it.  If you don't mind please check the link I posted.  Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine as posted here, but in the page you reference, you have two inputs with the ID of "destination".  That is causing your problem.  If you rename the ID of one of them, your code works.

For example:

HTML:

```
<input id="destinationMain" name="destination" placeholder="Choose Destination">
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#destinationMain").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
```

Comment: Scott, thank you so much, I am embarrassed.  I even did a search for the duplicate names, but one part comes through an include file and so didn't search there.  Again.  Thank you.  Best.

Comment: :) Glad I could help!  Some times you just need a fresh set of eyes on it.